# Make 2D array into 1D array in Processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to flatten a two dimensional array into a one dimensional array. This is what I currently have. I would like the flatten out my array so that the one dimensional array looks like this

```
   int[] oneDim = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ,9 ,10, 11, 12};
```

This is what I currently have. I dont really know how to go about doing this. All help and input is appreciated.

```
   void setup() {
   int[][] twoDim = { {1, 2, 3, 4},
                      {5, 6, 7, 8},
                      {9, 10, 11, 12} }; 

   int[] oneDim = new int[twoDim.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < twoDim.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < twoDim[i].length; j++) {
        oneDim[j] += twoDim[j][i];
      }                  
    }
   println(oneDim);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[][] twoDim = { {1, 2, 3, 4},
                   {5, 6, 7, 8},
                   {9, 10, 11, 12} }; 
int x = twoDim.length;
int y = twoDim[0].length;
int[] oneDim = new int[x*y];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
    oneDim[i*y + j] = twoDim[i][j];
  }
}
println(oneDim);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: the usual formula for mapping two dimensions to one is: `width*y + x`, where `width` is the number of elements in each row (4, in your case, as given by `twoDim[i].length`, assuming they are all the same length), 'x' is the iterator over columns (`j`, in your case), and `y` is the iterator over rows (`i` for you).

You will want to check that the size of your one dimensional array is sufficient to accept all the elements of `twoDim`.  It doesn't look big enough as it is - it needs to be `twoDim[i].length * twoDim.length` elements long, at least.

You're currently writing the same row of data over and over again, because you're assigning to `oneDim[j]` in the inner loop for every iteration of the outer loop.  Try assigning to `oneDim` (once it is of appropriate size) using the formula I suggested at the start of this answer instead.